$|S=\{\alpha \in \mathbb{R} | n $ divides $a_n= \sum_{k=1}^n [k\alpha] , \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \}|$=?
Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R} $
and  $a_n = [\alpha ]+[2\alpha] + ...+[n\alpha] , \forall n\in \mathbb{N} $
where $[ . ]$ is the floor function.
Consider $S=\{\alpha \in \mathbb{R} | n$ divides $a_n , \forall n\in \mathbb{N} \}$.
Then
$(a) S$ is nowhere dense.
$(b) S\cap(2024 , 2026)=\phi $
$(c) S$ is a finite set
$(d)| S\cap \{ 1, 2, 3 ,...,2024\}| \le 1012$
My attempt:-
We have $k[\alpha]\le [k\alpha] \le k\alpha  ,\forall k\in \mathbb{N} , \alpha\in \mathbb{R}  $
Adding from $k=1$ to $n$
$\frac{n(n+1)}2[\alpha] \le a_n \le \frac{n(n+1)}2 \alpha   $
If $\alpha\in \mathbb{Z} $ ,then $[\alpha]=\alpha$ and so from above $a_n=\frac{n(n+1)}2 \alpha$
If $\alpha$ is odd integer and since $n$ divides $a_n, \forall n$ , we must $\frac{n+1}2 \in \mathbb{N} $ , so $n$ must be odd, a contradiction .
Thus if $\alpha\in \mathbb{Z}$ , it must be even .
Now it easy to show $\frac{[n\alpha]}n \rightarrow \alpha$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$
Let $a_n= nq_n$ for some $q_n\in \mathbb{Z} $ and $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$
Thus $\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{n+1} =\frac{[(n+1)\alpha]}{n+1} \rightarrow \alpha$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$
So $q_{n+1} - \frac n{n+1} q_n \rightarrow \alpha$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$
Keeping in mind $\{q_n\} $ is integer sequence , I wanted to show it is eventually constant but unable to do so .
Update : $q_n \rightarrow \infty $ as $ n\rightarrow \infty$
Thus $ \frac{q_{n+1}}{q_n} \rightarrow 1 $ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ by dividing both sides of above limit by $q_n$
How may I proceed ? Hints Please.

You should use $\emptyset$ instead of the Greek letter phi. Anyway, is it a multiple choice question, or are these all properties of $S$?

@BrunoB B Yes , it's a multiple choice question

This is Problem 1 from the IMO 2024. There are several solutions to this problem, which you can find on AoPS. In short, $S = 2\mathbb{Z}$, meaning $S$ is precisely the set of even integers.
From this, you can conclude that the correct answers are (a), (b), and (d). Note that (c) does not work because $S$ is an infinite set.
